# Objective-C main.m doesn't specify which app delegate and it still works

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Working through the tutorial here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/01_CreatingProject.html

I notice that in main.m in supporting files, they say that the initialization happens here:

```
@autoreleasepool {
   return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorldAppDelegate class]));
}
```

This makes sense. It selects HelloWorldAppDelegate as the program begins. In mine however, that I used with the single view template, the initialization values are null:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Where does it specify which application delegate to run? I ran it and it works fine but not knowing why something works bugs me. Is it declared in another file?

Answer (score 2):

It's set in the xib/nib file. This is mentioned in the [documentation for UIApplicationMain()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain).